# Logstash metrics per input

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

With logstash metrics I'm able to know what the total event rate is for each logstash instance. However how can I tell what the rate of events is for each input type. For example lets say we have input A and input B. Would something like this work?

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 7654
    tags => [ "A" ]
  }
  tcp {
    port => 7655
    tags => [ "B" ]
  }
}

filter {
  if "A" in [tags] {
    metrics {
        meter => "metricsa"
        add_tag => "metrics_A"
    }
  } else if "B" in [tags] {
    metrics {
        meter => "metricsb"
        add_tag => "metrics_B"
    }
  }
}

output {
  if "metrics_A" in [tags] {
    graphite {
        host => "10.1.1.1"
        metrics_format => "test.*"
        include_metrics => [ "metricsa.*" ]
        fields_are_metrics => true
    }
 } else if "metrics_B" in [tags] {
    graphite {
        host => "10.1.1.1"
        metrics_format => "test.*"
        include_metrics => [ "metricsb.*" ]
        fields_are_metrics => true
    }
 }
}
```

Is there no way to gather ingestion metrics for each input type?